# CodeQl Analysis for C#

Tags: c#, github, workflow, codeql

I am a new beginner to CodeQl. I have been trying to find security vulnerabilities within GitHub by enabling the default method.

However, the default method is not enough for C# for some reason. I was wondering why. Moreover, I decided to go with the advanced config but it fails because of the autobuild. So, I decided to try to write my own build commands, which I am unsure of what to use. The my boss decided to see if it works with a .NET yaml file. I have already created a `.csproj` and `.sln` file, and now I was wondering how I can fix it. I am going to provide the link to my github:https://github.com/CISSSXA1/CSHARPtest3. If anyone has any suggestion on how I can fix this problem. Please let me know.

Comment: Is this still relevant? It looks like the workflow on your GitHub project runs successfully now. Unless this was caused by a typo, maybe it would be good if you added an answer to this question here yourself, since the answer might be useful for others too.